# Integrating Hikvision Attendance Hardware with Odoo for Biometric Time Attendance

Tags: python, odoo, hikvision

I am currently considering using Odoo as a human resource management solution. I have a specific requirement regarding an existing hikvision Attendance Hardware and want to know if Odoo can support it inorder for employee time attendance to be tracked biometrically. I am aware that there are apps on the Odoo app store for specific ztecko hardware integration, but I'm interested to if there is anyone who has successfully integrated or has any ideas on how to integrate hikvision hardware with Odoo.

Any and all suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well as I see, Odo is web based software and you could modify add/delete/modify/logs functions to actually add POST/PUT/GET request towards hikvision ISAPI endpoints.

If SAME-ORIGIN policy is active then you can make an ASP.NET proxy on localhost of T&A server and relay data over proxy.

Hikvision ISAPI for ACS(google this for documentation)

Overall could be a cool project if you make it.
I have made Hikvision integration with 3rd party webbased T&A using described logic (not allowed to name software)